# Webpage is sometimes unresponsive to postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am working on an ASP.NET project on VS 2010 that is completely local as of now and a strange problem keeps popping up which I can't seem to explain.

Essentially, sometimes when I perform an action that causes some sort of postback event (e.g. change the selection of a drop down list which repopulates a gridview based on the drop down list selection), the page will "flicker" like a normal postback but then result in a blank page.

Since this occured rather infrequently I decided to ignore it for the time being and focus on other aspects of the project. However, after I implement partial postbacks using AJAX, I think I may have found out what is happening.

With partial postbacks, the page now is not reloading every time a postback occurs, and I noticed that occasionally, performing an action that should cause a postback does absolutely nothing.

So my hypothesis is that somehow, the event triggered causes a postback but then gets hung up somewhere? I'm rather new to web programming so I'm at a loss at this point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking for help with?  Confirming your suspicion?

Comment: Well what can I do at this point? I can't leave it where sometimes nothing happens when a postback should occur.

Comment: OK, so you're looking for help in fixing the problem.  Could you give a bit more information on what you do to reproduce the problem, any sore points that seems to reliably recreate it, things like that in your post?  It's really hard to give advice on how to go forward if we can't tell what is causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: It's really exactly as I described it which is why I'm having a lot of trouble understanding it as well. Basically sometimes actions that should cause a postback ends up doing nothing, be it a button press, a checkbox being checked, a change in drop down list selection. I'm not really sure what else I can say.

Comment: And if you have any suggestions as to how I can better debug it, that would help as well.

Comment: I'll do my best, but there are precious few details in the question so I apologize in advance if my forthcoming answer is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an intermittent error that affects the large majority of your website without giving you any errors or logging.  This is colloquially known as 'a huge headache'.

Here are a few steps you can take to hopefully get more information on the problem:

- On your browser/client side, install a developer add-on such as Firebug that allows you to step through your AJAX/javascript as you make the calls.  Watch for anything that looks odd or that might imply you are failing to address information critical for the postback.  Javascript's robustness means that it can very often do things that are logically nonsense and not have a huge crash with informative errors like you would expect out of a more particular language like C#.
- On the connection, install Fiddler and keep a log of all the requests and responses that go out over the line.  When you manage to reproduce the error, inspect the request that went to the server very carefully to see if it's any different from others.  If you get a response, investigate that too.
- On the server side, try to drop a visual studio debugger into the web server instance so you have visibility on when something is hit and when it's not.  If you are able to do this, you can at least see if it is getting all the way into your code when it goes to fail.

It may also help to ask if there's been any known hardware problems in your office/work space recently.  It sounds really unlikely since everything else is working, but when dealing with a problem like this it's a good idea to check all your bases.